# Parse a C source file and get a list of functions

Tags: c#, c, parsing

I want to write a program in C# that uses a library to parse C source files, and provides me with a data structure containing all the functions and parameters associated found in it.

I don't need to know what is actually inside the function or anything else for that matter.

What would be a good library to do that?

Comment: Is there any alternative to ANTLR? I honestly can't for the life of me make it work with Visual Studio C# Express 2010... The documentation is a mess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ANTLR can do what you'd like. It has a C preprocessor and ANSI C grammar.

(http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list)

Comment: Thanks for this, this thing is really overwhelming tho. If I understand correctly, I must use the ANSI C grammar file to generate the source file that I'll use in my C# application? What is the use of the C Preprocessor? And also how do I use it? There is no Readme coming with it

Comment: I've used this page http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557075 to try and use it from Visual C# Express 2010 but I get the following error message : The type or namespace name 'GrammarRuleAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I guess I should ask the ANTLR forums!

Comment: @Leo: I honestly have never used ANTLR, I only know what it can do. Maybe this should be another SO question on question on the ANTLR forums?

Comment: oh okay, thought you knew it. Thanks for all the input and sorry to be a pain haha! I'll go ask the ANTLR people.

Comment: @Leo: Sorry if I implied that. I am just here to help :)